# Bluemix live sync adds to the application memory

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

I'm using Live Sync for a node.js application.

When I activate "Live Edit" using the Web Editor, the application is restarted and it takes +258mb of memory. If the application is configured to use 128mg and I activate "Live Edit," it is restarted with 384mg. It happens also with bl command line.

This is a problem for accounts with restricted memory. Is this normal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal, as the utilities that enable Live Edit (and the debug tools) consume application memory, and cannot run with only 128mb. For a more consistent experience, additional memory is required.

It would make sense for the `bl` client and Web IDE to indicate that additional memory will be required and added. This memory requirement should be clearly communicated; I'll get the proper team engaged.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, just a note, it is not because of the 128mb, if I set the app to use 512 it goes up to 768. So Live Edit needs additional 256mb to be activated.

Comment: Right, I should have clarified.  To ensure that the user's application runs exactly as it would without the utilities, we add the additional memory that the Live Edit needs.  For example, an intensive application may use nearly the full 512MB, so to deliver a consistent experience, we add more memory on top.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please what is in your `manifest.yml` file?  The `manifest.yml` file will override settings with pushing your app.

Comment: applications:
- disk_quota: 1024M
  host: DummySrv
  name: DummySrv
  path: .
  domain: eu-gb.mybluemix.net
  instances: 1
  memory: 128M